# Every derived table must have its own alias error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) 
FROM (

SELECT s.cost
FROM sandwiches AS s
WHERE s.name =  "Cheese Steak"
)
UNION (

SELECT p.cost
FROM pizza AS p
WHERE TYPE =  "Plain"
AND SIZE =  "L"
)
```

That gives me an error of:

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to alias your temp tables

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) 
FROM
(
  (
  SELECT s.cost
  FROM sandwiches AS s
  WHERE s.name =  "Cheese Steak"
  ) AS T1
UNION 
  (
  SELECT p.cost
  FROM pizza AS p
  WHERE TYPE =  "Plain"
  AND SIZE =  "L"
  ) AS T2
) AS T
```

Comment: Yea I don't think your query is structured correctly. Looks like ypercube gave a good answer

Comment: I think you need another set of parenthesis, starting after the first from and ending at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the whole Sum?

```
SELECT 
  ( SELECT SUM(s.cost)
    FROM sandwiches AS s
    WHERE s.name =  "Cheese Steak"
  )
+
  ( SELECT SUM(p.cost)
    FROM pizza AS p
    WHERE p.TYPE =  "Plain"
      AND p.SIZE =  "L"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following form should do the job:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM (
  SELECT cost FROM sandwiches WHERE name = "Cheese Steak"
  UNION 
  SELECT cost FROM pizza WHERE TYPE = "Plain" AND SIZE = "L"
) as temp
```

MySQL only requires a temporary table name for the subselect.